# Do programs look over all the code and then run, or does it run line by line?

Tags: c

To put things in perspective, here's a simple program in C that asks the user to input their name, and then the program says "Hello, [your name]":

```
void PrintName(string name);

int main(void)
{
 printf("Your name: ");
 string s = GetString();
 PrintName(s);
}

void PrintName(string name)
{
 printf("Hello, %s\n,name);
}
```

In line 7, I've written PrintName(s), however, PrintName is not defined until the end.

My question: If a program runs things line by line, when it first encounters PrintName(s), wouldn't the program not understand how PrintName is defined (because the function definition comes after, not before) and thus not output a name?

Comment: the program is statically compiled, so it goes over all the code first if you like (in C anyway)

Comment: Well, you are required to _declare_ (tell the compiler its name and how it looks like - simply put) a name before you use it. If that's what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that programming languages are there to make our lives easier; writing binary machine code (1's and 0's) is a pain, so languages let us express ourselves more concisely.

Some languages are interpreted (goes through line by line, roughly speaking), some are statically compiled (a compiler goes through all the code and generates an executable when it's done), and some do something else entirely.

C is statically compiled.

```
void PrintName(string name);
```

This is a function declaration. This tells the compiler "a function called `PrintName` that takes a `string` argument exists".

So when your program is being compiled and the identifier `PrintName` is hit, the compiler knows about it, can check you're giving it a string (amongst other things) and carries on happily.

The compiler later comes across the definition of `PrintName` and uses that to generate the executable.

If you declare a function, but do not define it, you'll later get an error along the lines of `undefined reference to MyFunction`, which is saying "you told me this function definition existed somewhere, but I can't find it".

Answer (score 2):

You are getting confused between compiling and running code.

Your code is compiled first when you build it so it understands what printName is then. Later you run the code that then runs the command called "printName". So it already "knows" what it is from when you compiled it.

Answer (score 2):

the program is not "executed" so to speak in the language you wrote it in. Technically speaking, the only real execution language is binary, the computer chips dont understand code, they only understand on or off.

When you write your code, it is compiled into lower level languages like assembly, and eventually to binary. All the connections you make in your code are created at that time, before execution.

Answer (score 1):

C programs are compiled before you're able to run them. This includes reading *all* of the sources and building a graph with all functions and entry points. In general, it is possible to call or otherwise use a function defined anywhere, but in C you should declare a *forward* prototype if your callee function is defined below the place it is used.

So, C programs are not executed line-by-line.

Some scripting languages have a notion of sml line-by-line execution, but mainly it is really statement-by-statement. I.e. an `if` line cannot be executed at all, because it only controls the program flow. So, interpreter must read the entire body of the statement (see below) before it is able to correctly execute them.

```
if (condition) {
    ...
} <- here it starts executing the entire sentence

function foo(bar) {
    while (true) {
        bar = bar - bar
    } <- not here!
} <- last brace closed, statement is complete
```